# Hot to get content from inside a pop up iframe?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, nuxt.js

So I am trying to open an URL in a pop-up window and get the contents.

**This is what I have so far**

```
  let url = this.status_url_response
  let win = window.open();
  let htm = '<iframe id="pop" width="560" height="315" src='+url+  'frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
  win.document.write(htm);
console.log(win.document.getElementById('pop'));
```

However, when I `console.log` the `id`, all I get is the `htm` variable.  Any idea as to how to get the contents from inside?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you want to access the content of an iframe, like you topic says, or access the `id` of an element, like you tried with "when I console.log the id"?

Comment: @Fabalance the contents from the iframe

Answer (score 1):

Before you read the solution for your request, please note: **You can´t read the content of an iframe, if it´s another domain!**

Get the content of your iframe:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrameId");
```

Get a element from your iframe:

```
var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("myElementId")
```